# TinyMCE insert content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have 2 textarea in a webpage which use tinyMCE.

```
<textarea id="id1" rows="10" cols="50" name="name1"></textarea>
<textarea id="id2" rows="10" cols="50" name="name2"></textarea>
```

On version 3 of TinyMCE, I was able to do this

```
$('#id1').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "content");
```

Now on version 4, I try to use the same code, but it didn't work. So, how can I insert content into the specific targeted textarea?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are several possible ways.

In case your editor with "id1" is the active Editor:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'your content');
```

In case you want to use the id:

```
tinymce.get("id1").execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'your content');
```

In case you only have two editors and your editor with "id1" has been initialized first:

```
tinymce.editors[0].execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'your content');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using `tinymce.get("id1")` and it works fine until I test on IE8. On IE8, I get the error `Object expected` when I try to insert data into tinymce. How can I fix that?

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this?

Comment: How to run execCommand when `{inline: true}` ? The above code will put 'your content' to outside the textarea!

Comment: @Thariama, you are right. However it turns out that if I replace the `textarea` with `div`, then it works!  And for **Tiny MCE** 4.x, the insert content code can be simplified to `tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('your content');`

Comment: Thank you,this saved my time

Answer (score 2):

It actually can be done with

```
tinymce.get("id1").execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,"content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with your dom id as arguement:

```
tinymce.get("YOUR DOM ID").execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'use your output content');
```